# Keep ListView scroll position and data when popping fragment stack

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Here's my situation, I have 1 `Activity`, and 2 `Fragments`. When the `Activity` is started it loads a `Fragment`, let's call it **list**, into the view (in a `FrameLayout` filling the screen). **List** simply lists blogs posts which are retreived via an async HTTP call to out web api. When a blog is clicked in **list** is runs this method in the `Activity`

```
public void loadBlog(FragmentBlog.Blog theBlog) {
    blog = theBlog;
    FragmentBlogDetails d = new FragmentBlogDetails();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(KEY_BLOG, theBlog);
    d.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, d).addToBackStack("Detail").commit();
}
```

Then the blog loads up and is displayed fine. Now, once I press the back key, my **list** `Fragment` calls onCreateView again and I have to run the async call again to populate my list, which reset the scroll to the top too. How can I keep my data for needing to be fetched again, and keep the view so the scroll stays where it is?

Here's my onCreateView method in the list `Fragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("FragmentBlog", "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blog, container, false);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.the_list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    if (baa != null) {
        list.setAdapter(baa);
    }
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    asyncForBlogs();
    return view;
}
```

If you need any other bits of code let me know and I'll post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save index of last item user clicked. Define a index variable in your fragment and when users clicked on an item store item index in it. Then save data in onSaveInstanceState Call back. You can save other data like this. But make sure the data you put inside bundle is not so big. Do not put any images or videos here!

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("index",index);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

after saving your data you can access it in onCreate method. like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getInt("index");
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
    }
}
```

smoothScrollToPosition scroll your list view to the last place you were been.